# Clarifying Essbase @Relative and @Parentval

Tags: essbase

I am new to Essbase, it would be very kind of someone to help me understand this script that I see.
I have the following outline:

```
  Outline: XXX
      Product
           A
                P1
                  xx1
                    xx2
           B
                P2
                  yy1
                    yy2
      Account             
           X
               zeroOneFlag
           Y
                Premium
      Company
            alpha
                Gen Acct
            beta
```

I have simplified the outline for this discussion (there are other members for each of product/account/company)

I see the following script:

```
            fix ("Gen Acct",@relative("P1",0),@relative("P2",0))
                            "Premium" = @Parentval(Product,"Premium") * "zeroOneFlag";
            endfix
```

Now how do I visualize what is going on ?

I have the following confusion:

1> I have to figure out the @relative("P1",0) and @relative("P2",0) that will give me the co-ordinates that are getting update.

2> how is the accumulation happening with the command @Parentval(Product,"Premium") .

It would be very kind for someone to clarify.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

@RELATIVE("P1", 0) gives you the level-0 members of the member P1. In your example that would be xx2. Level-0 members are just members without children (leaf nodes). There isn't a real accumulation happening in this script. It's simply setting the value of Premium (for intersections of Gen Acct and level-0 descendants of P1 and P2. It's saying "For the members in this FIX statement, set the value of Premium to be the Premium value of the current parent in Product, times the zeroOneFlag member. You might try calculating the whole cube and evaluating the results, I don't think you really want to do the calculation this way.